# Silverlight Image Cropping

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Does anybody knows how to image cropping in silverlight without any library.

I have Child window and inside the child window I havev a image and this image center one rectange is there so I can panning the image to the around the rectange and selecet the perticular part of the image and this selected part I want to crop.

Also I am using WriteableBitmap and try to Crop, this will not work if correct me if I am wrong.

sheetRectangle.Children is the Image.

```
            foreach (ucPicRect item in sheetRectangle.Children)
            {
                WriteableBitmap obj = new WriteableBitmap(item.imgCell.Source as BitmapSource);
                obj.Crop(0,0,400,400);
                obj.Invalidate();
                item.imgCell.Effect = dlgcwEditPhoto.imgEdit.Effect;
                item.imgCell.Source = obj;// dlgcwEditPhoto.imgEdit.Source;

            }
```

Thanks...!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this utility function to crop your image

```
 public static WriteableBitmap cropImage(Image image, double[] coordonnee)
    {
        Image cloneImage = new Image();
        cloneImage.Source = image.Source;
        RectangleGeometry myRec = new RectangleGeometry();
        myRec.Rect = new Rect(coordonnee[0], coordonnee[1], coordonnee[2], coordonnee[3]);
        cloneImage.Clip = myRec;
        TranslateTransform t = new TranslateTransform();
        t.X = -coordonnee[0];
        t.Y = -coordonnee[1];
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(cloneImage, t);
        wb.Invalidate();
        return wb;

    }
```

good luck !!